# Receiving Http 503 with upstream error while calling Cloud Run in h2c mode

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

While making a HTTP/2.0 request from client (using library [httpx](https://github.com/encode/httpx)) to fully managed Cloud Run (Custom application (Spring boot with jetty) and [ESPv2](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions)) some requests end up in `503` with response body as `upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: remote refused stream reset`. This issue seems to be persistent (~2-3 requests fails for ~2000 requests in an hour on an avg) and have started to notice only after enabling the HTTP/2.0 (h2c) in cloud run configuration by following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/http2).

Things tried so far to resolve this issue:

1. Changed Tomcat webserver to Jetty webserver in Spring boot but still no improvement (Still receiving same error code and response)
2. Switched python client library from [Urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.util.html#module-urllib3.util.retry) to [httpx](https://github.com/encode/httpx) (still the same issue)
3. Tried printing Access logs in jetty and tomcat. When request fails with 503 on Cloud run, no access log is printed indicating it never reached the application

This feels more like issue with Cloud run when using it in H2c

Has anyone faced similar issue and was able to resolve it?

Additional Cloud run info: Cloud Run is running with following configuration 2CPU, 2GB memory, 15 min instances and 80 concurrency. This configuration was same before and after enabling H2c in Cloud run (no requests use to fail with this error message before enabling h2c, after enabling randomly some requests fail with this error)

Comment: I have found this [community question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1070510/application-works-locally-but-fails-with-502-in-cloud-run-upstream-connect-e) that has a similar issue, the solution was to disable the http/2 end-to-end and it fixed the issue, can you try that?

Comment: I looked into the issue, but the problem over there was that the go-code in his server was not supporting H2c and hence only solution for him was to disable the H2c configuration. I have a completely different problem. In my case Springboot and jetty suport H2c (by following this configuration  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/reference/html//howto.html#howto.webserver.configure-http2.jetty). and the application works both locally and in production with cloud run. Only a subset of requests fails randomly with this error

Comment: I see, in that case, being an intermittent issue makes it hard to figure it out. I would suggest you to create a Bug Report in [Google's Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=608076&template=0) so that they can check this and either fix it if this is a bug or give you some insights on what might be the cause of this.